# How to solve "query completed with an empty output na" when response should be sum of the cell values in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is a copy of another excel sheet I'm working on, this is the query I've:

`=query(indirect("'"&VLOOKUP(C6,BANK_CARDS!$B$2:$F$4,5, false)&"'!$B$3:K"), "select sum(J) where F='"&$H6&"' and G='"&I6&"' and H="&C6&" and month(C)+1="&month(today())&" label sum(J)''",0)`

This part, gets the cell value to get the name of the credit card which we'll be getting the data transactions:

```
indirect("'"&VLOOKUP(C6,BANK_CARDS!$B$2:$F$4,5, false)&"'!$B$3:K")
```

This should return the sum of the quantity in J based on the other conditions (on the same month, same credit card number, category and subcategory).

```
"select sum(J) where F='"&$H6&"' and G='"&I6&"' and H="&C6&" and month(C)+1="&month(today())&" label sum(J)''"
```

I don't know how to fix or improve this, here is the link of the google-sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iAJrF7syT8TBz1emKnnioQvZs7Z-5q5koYLGA419rOs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Bank Id` column values were formatted as **text**, thus the query parameter has to be in text format as well:

```
=query(indirect("'"&VLOOKUP(C6,BANK_CARDS!$B$2:$F$4,5, false)&"'!$B$3:K"), "select sum(J) where F='"&$H6&"' and G='"&I6&"' and H='"&C6&"' and month(C)+1="&month(today())&" label sum(J)''",0)
```

This one in particular: `H='"&C6&"'`

From your test sheet it now displays:

[image]